# Lost info when changing language on Ubuntu

Tags: bug-reporting

I change the language on ubuntu and lost all pictures, music, downloads, documents when updated the 'folder's name'.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that in RECENT access can see OLD files. in HOME folder are both folders. english and spanish, al content are on that old folder. just need to cut and past.